# Return results from 3 tables where the number of results should be equal to the number of rows in table 1 multiplied by the number of rows in table 3

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-view

**I have a PostgreSQL database with three tables:**

- `user`: A list of users of the application. Primary key is `user_id`.
- `course`: A catalog of courses that users can enroll into. Primary key is `course_id`.
- `enrollment`: Records of the users' enrollment into courses. Primary key is `enrollment_id`.

**Relations between the tables:**

- The `enrollment` table has two foreign keys that can not be null:

  - `enrollment.user_id` references `user.user_id`.
  - `enrollment.course_id` references `course.course_id`.
- If `user1` is enrolled in `course1`, there should be only one record in the `enrollment` table that can be used to join `user1` to `course1`.
- If `user1` is **not** enrolled in `course1`, **no** record exists in the `enrollment` table to join `user1` to `course1`.

**The problem:**

- I can not find out how to write a database view which, if I have 2 users and 3 courses, returns 6 rows that look like this:

```
user_id | course_id | enrollment_id
-------------------------------------
user1   | course1   | enrollment id of user1 for course1 or null
user1   | course2   | enrollment id of user1 for course2 or null
user1   | course3   | enrollment id of user1 for course3 or null
user2   | course1   | enrollment id of user2 for course1 or null
user2   | course2   | enrollment id of user2 for course2 or null
user2   | course3   | enrollment id of user2 for course3 or null
```

**Some context:**

- I can not change anything about the database.
- I am not concerned about performance.

**My work in progress:**

I candidly hoped that this would work:

```
select user.user_id, course.course_id, enrollment.enrollment_id
from user
full outer join enrollment on enrollment.user_id = user.user_id
full outer join course on course.course_id = enrollment.course_id
```

This query does not return the results I'm expecting due to the fact that there isn't an `enrollment` record for courses the users are not enrolled into. The results, for example, look more like this:

```
user_id | course_id | enrollment_id
-------------------------------------
user1   | null      | null
user2   | course1   | enrollment id of user2 for course1
user2   | course2   | enrollment id of user2 for course2
```

Which is not what I expect, as I wish the table to return 3 records for `user1`, who is not enrolled in any course, instead of only one row where `course_id` and `enrollment_id` are `null`. Similarly, a third record for `user2` is missing since they are not enrolled in `course3`, which is not what I'm hoping for.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cross join users & courses, left join enrollment:

```
select u.user_id, c.course_id, e.enrollment_id
from users u
cross join courses c
left join enrollment e
    on e.user_id = u.user_id
    and e.course_id = c.course_id
```

dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1c173d242bd29ea252f716e336832760) (Postgres 14)